# Cross-browser way to add a margin to a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, margin

One of my tables has 23 columns, so on most screens it overflows over the screen width. That's not a big deal, except that I'd like the table to keep a minimum space before window's border.

`margin-left` works, but somehow `margin-right` didn't work on `table`, nor the `tr`, nor even for the last `td` of the row. I've made a workaround for it by adding a text in `span` before the end of the `tr` :

```
<tr>(...)<td>(...)</td><span class='tableMarginRight'>XXXXX</span></tr>

.tableMarginRight {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

it works on Opera and Chrome, but not on Firefox. Anyone have other ideas?

**EDIT**: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s9pF5/)

Comment: could you add "sample" of the actual table (with just a few rows) and the css so we can fiddle around a bit and help you out better? we are lazy sorry, at least me xD

Comment: Is there an online example available? Probably would be good to have some more HTML/CSS context.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9pF5/) - as you can see here `margin-right` for `td.mar` doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

padding and margin doesn't work on tr. If you wanna add some space try applying it to the TD instead. Margin doesn't work.

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td class="pad-l">item</td>
        <td class="pad-r">item</td>
        <td class="pad-t">item</td>
        <td class="mar">margin</td>
    </tr>
</table>

.pad-l{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.pad-r{
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.pad-t{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.mar{
    margin: 30px 50px;
}
```

[Check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/ricbermo/dQVqk/)

Comment: I've tried it also, but it looks ok only on Chrome. On Opera I lost borders and on Chrome `visibility:hidden` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Margin betweens rows and columns can be removed with border-spacing and/or border-collapse.
The border between the table/cells and the window is the body margin, which you can remove with :

```
body {
    margin: 0px   
}
```

Comment: nope, cannot remove td's border with `border-spacing`, I can change it, but not remove